# FXCollections.reverse throwing UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, javafx

I am using `FXCollections.reverse` on a ObservableList created using `FXCollections.observableArrayList()`, and the method throws an **UnsupportedOperationException**. I have even tried to reverse a list created using `FXCollections.observableList(list)`, with different types of list, bu the reverse method keeps throwing the exception.

I am missing something?

P.S. I am using **JavaFX** on Linux.

Comment: Can you post some code? This works fine for me.

Comment: I am just doing

`...
ObservableList<AClass> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
FXCollections.reverse(list);
...`

I have actually gone through the JavaFX code and seems that (at least the version I have on linux), FXCollections.reverse is broken, as the list wrapper it is using to create any lists, does not have implemented the setAll() method.

Comment: Double checked. The code is there (my mistake). Still do not know what it can be

Comment: Which JDK version are you using? Can you edit your question to include  an actual complete executable example (should only require a main method with about 4-5 lines of code) and post the stack trace?

Comment: When I try to run your code, I just get a `StackOverflowError` if I add elements to the list (the handler for the list changing itself changes the list, causing the handler to get invoked, etc...)

Comment: It is weird ... anyway I finally ended up modifying my code (for different reasons) and currently have not the need to sort the list. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think that I found the issue. I was trying to call FXCollections.reverse() from the callback of a ListChangeListener for the same list. My was something like:

public class AClass {

```
private static ObservableList<Double> list;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Point> change) -> {
        while (change.next()) {
            if (change.wasRemoved() || change.wasAdded()) {
                doSomethingFunction();
            }
        }
    });
}

private static void doSomethingFunction() {
    FXCollections.reverse(list);
}
```

}